# Single login for both ProfileSharing and Payment using PayPal SDK

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying to implement a instant payment using `PayPal` `SDK`. Both profile sharing to get the email address of the user and payment was working well.

The problem that i'm was facing is that both `ProfileSharing` and Payment require user consent. And to get the consent both `ProfileSharing` and Payment is launching different Login screen, because of this the user needs to login two time for this process to be complete.

Is there any way to do `ProfileSharing` and Payment from a single login.

Here is what i am doing right now:

```
//for payment
        public void onInstantPaymentPressed() {

                PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(PaypalTransactionActity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

                // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
                intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

                intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
            }


        private PayPalPayment getThingToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
                return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("50.5"), "USD", "sample item",
                        paymentIntent);
            }


    //for profile sharing
       public void onProfileSharingPressed() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PaypalTransactionActity.this, PayPalProfileSharingActivity.class);

            // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
            intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

            intent.putExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_REQUESTED_SCOPES, getOauthScopes());

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING);
        }

        private PayPalOAuthScopes getOauthScopes() {
            /* create the set of required scopes
             * Note: see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/attributes/ for mapping between the
             * attributes you select for this app in the PayPal developer portal and the scopes required here.
             */
            Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(PayPalOAuthScopes.PAYPAL_SCOPE_EMAIL));
            return new PayPalOAuthScopes(scopes);
        }
```